# How Maximum days restriction in DateRangePicker for the React?

Tags: daterangepicker, react-daterange-picker

How Maximum days restriction in [DateRangePicker](https://github.com/hypeserver/react-date-range) for the React can be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to solve the requirement as below. Sharing if any finds this useful to use,

**This restricts selection before and after from the range startDate by a maxDays.**

```sh
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react"
import {makeStyles} from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { DateRangePicker } from 'react-date-range';
import 'react-date-range/dist/styles.css'; // main style file
import 'react-date-range/dist/theme/default.css';
import { addDays, subDays } from "date-fns"; // theme css file


const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root:{
    // padding: 16
  }
}))

const selectionRange = {
  startDate: new Date(),
  endDate: new Date(),
  key: 'dateRange',
}

const DateRange = (props) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const {
    dateRange, 
    onSelectPeriod, 
    hides, 
    minDate, 
    maxDate,
    maxDays
  } = props
  const [period, setPeriod] = useState(selectionRange)
  const [miDate, setMiDate] = useState(new Date(1970, 1, 1))
  const [maDate, setMaDate] = useState(new Date(2100, 1, 1))
 
  useEffect(()=>{
    if(dateRange) {
      setPeriod(dateRange)
    } 
    
    if(hides)
      hides.map((num, index) => {
        (document.getElementsByClassName('rdrStaticRanges')[0]).childNodes[num-index].remove();
      })

    if(minDate != null) setMiDate(minDate)
    if(maxDate != null) setMaDate(maxDate)
  },[])

  useEffect(()=>{
    onSelectPeriod(period)
  },[period])

  const handleSelect = (ranges) => {
    if(ranges === undefined) return
    // console.log("DateRangePicker: ", ranges)    
    setPeriod(ranges.dateRange)

    // set to restrict only maxDays range selection; post selection it reset to as initial for further selection
    if(maxDays != null) {
      if(ranges.dateRange.startDate.getTime() === ranges.dateRange.endDate.getTime()){
        // REstrict maxDays before or after for selection
        setMiDate(subDays(ranges.dateRange.startDate, maxDays-1))
        const mDate = addDays(ranges.dateRange.startDate, maxDays-1)
        if(mDate.getTime() <= maxDate.getTime()) setMaDate(mDate)
      } else {
        // RESET as INITIAL
        if(minDate != null) {
          setMiDate(minDate) 
        } else {
          setMiDate(new Date(1970, 1, 1))
        }

        if(maxDate != null) {
          setMaDate(maxDate)
        } else {
          setMaDate(new Date(2100, 1, 1))
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <DateRangePicker
        ranges={[period]}
        onChange={handleSelect}
        minDate={miDate}
        maxDate={maDate}
      />
    </div>
  )
}

export default DateRange
```